# Simulate programmatic button click using Phantomjs and test with Jasmine

Tags: jquery, bdd, jasmine, phantomjs

Using the [phantomjs-jasmine](https://github.com/mrosati84/phantomjs-jasmine) to make a simple test

```
//example_spec.js
describe("Click button", function() {
  it ("should be become 3", function() {
      var i = 0;
      var button_element = $('#button');
      console.log(button_element.text());
      while(i < 3 ) {
          button_element[0].click();
      console.log($('#counter').text());
        i ++;
      }
      console.log($('#counter').text());
    expect($('#counter').text()).toEqual('3');
  });

});



//example.js
var main = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var count = document.getElementById('counter');
        count.innerText = parseInt(count.innerText) + 1;
    });
}
window.addEventListener('load', main);




window.addEventListener('load', main);

//index.html
....
<p id='counter'>0</p>
<button id='button'></button>
....
```

The testing result is really strange

```
hantomjs lib/run_jasmine_test.coffee spec/TestRunner.html
Starting...
0
0
0

Click button : should be become 3
Error: Expected '1' to equal '3'.

Finished
-----------------
1 spec, 1 failure in 0.033s.

ConsoleReporter finished
```

some thing must be wrong in my code, any idea?

---

**//example-updated-jquery-version.js**

```
var main = function() {
    var button = $('#button');

    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $('#counter').text(parseInt($('#counter').text()) + 1);
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `innerText()` is supported by PhantomJS?
If you try the same snippet on Mozilla it won't work, for you're expected to use `textContent()`.

Try to use [jQuery's `text()` method instead](http://jqapi.com/#p=text), which is cross-browser.

Update: innerText() is an IE specific method, thus you have to use textContent. For further reference see [this MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: Hi @mamoo, that's for letting me know innerText() is not the way to go, I've changed the code to jquery version, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I've upload the code to github https://github.com/markson/jasmine-phantomjs-test-example, please have a look

Comment: This is because you attach the 'click' event callback AFTER executing your jasmine test. Pay attention to the order of your operations ;)

Comment: but `example.js` which include the event handler, in include in the html before the test file, how could it AFTER the jasmine test

Comment: This is the way you've instructed it to work. In example.js main() is a callback of the 'load' event, which is fired when the page is loaded (that happens to be after you've run your jasmine fixtures). Try to launch specrunner with a browser, putting a breakpoint on your spec method and another one in your main function in example.js ...

Comment: you got the point. Thanks so much. I've taken off the onLoad event, and move the script of main.js to the bottom line of the `<body>`, and It works

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a better way to let phantomjs to run the test after the main.js loading